# ЗамОк и зАмок

Tags: омонимы

Интересно, слова "замОк" и "зАмок" — это просто омонимы или оба происходят от слова "замыкать"? И, если так, то почему у них разное ударение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Почему разное" - это вряд ли кто ответит, так уж сложилось.
Если Вы про то, как произошли слова, то зАмок от польского zamek, которое в свою очередь - калька с немецкого. В польском ударение всегда на предпоследний слог.

Происходит от польск. zamek, которое через чешск. zámek калькирует ср.-в.-нем. slōʒ «замок, запор», затем «перемычка долины, оврага и под.». Последнее в свою очередь является калькой лат. clūsa «запор, форт, укрепление». Известно с XVII в. (Беседа трёх святит.). Связано с замыкать (замкнуть). Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; 
(вики)

Что касается замОк, то это обычное русское образование от замыкать. Ударение в русских словах подобного типа обычно на суффикс: оселок, звонок, вьюнок, вершок. Тут, правда, везде свои особенности в словообразовании и значении суффикса, но ударение везде тяготеет к последнему слогу.

Очень спорен вопрос о том, можно ли в подобных случаях слова считать родственными. Насколько знаю, большинство лингвистов сходятся во мнении, что слова, пришедшие в язык разными путями, родственными не считаются, даже если на каком-то этапе у них был общий корень.

Согласен, это омографы. Хотя вопрос не об этом.

Answer (score 2):

Это разновидность омонимов. А именно - омографы: пишутся одинаково, а произносятся по-разному.